# How can I use an Object in an Object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to put an object as a property into another object:

```
    @interface Options
{
      Guarantor *guarantors;
      NSString *success_message;
      NSString *source;
}

@end
```

And this is my Guarantor object:

```
@interface Guarantor{
   BOOL *status;
   NSString *message;
   NSInteger *number;

}

@end
```

I am met with an error that says `unknown type name Guarantor`?
Why is this?

Comment: Aside: are you _sure_ you want pointers to BOOL?

Comment: @Gereon is there an alternative or a better way?

Comment: Sure, just use `BOOL status`. Same goes for `NSInteger number` - usually you don't use pointers and memory allocations for scalars.

Comment: @Gereon, thank you, I am new to Objective C. and so far I feel it is harder that writing C++

Answer (score 0):

Change order of declarations (in Objective-C it does matter)... and make them is-a NSObject, it is little sense w/o that.

```
// 1st
@interface Guarantor: NSObject {
   BOOL *status;
   NSString *message;
   NSInteger *number;

}
@end

// 2nd
@interface Options: NSObject {
      Guarantor *guarantors;
      NSString *success_message;
      NSString *source;
}
@end
```

alternate is to use forward declaration like

```
@class Guarantor; // forward declaration

// 1st
@interface Options: NSObject {
      Guarantor *guarantors;
      NSString *success_message;
      NSString *source;
}
@end

// 2nd
@interface Guarantor: NSObject {
   BOOL *status;
   NSString *message;
   NSInteger *number;

}
@end
```